# Proving that if $a$ and $b$ are two positive real numbers, then $a < b \iff \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b} \iff \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am so lost. We have been learning about set, sequences, infimum and supremum over the past week or two, and I have no idea how to apply it to my homework question. Here it is:

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two positive real numbers. Prove that
$$a < b \iff \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b} \iff \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$$

Comment: If you divide $a<b$ by $ab$ what do you get ?

Comment: I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: 1/b<1/a but I don't think we are allowed to divide or multiply inequalities because we haven't gone over it yet

Comment: Can you tell us what you are allowed to do then?

Comment: Another hint : $a$ and $b$ are the squares of $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion based on what we are "allowed to do" or not. My proff is very adament on using only what we have proven in class. I appreciate everyones help and I think I know how to get the answer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

\begin{align}
a<b&\iff b-a>0\\&\iff (\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a})>0\\&\iff \sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a} >0\\&\iff \sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}.
\end{align}

In a similar way

\begin{align}
\frac 1b<\frac 1a&\iff \frac 1a-\frac 1b>0\\&\iff ab\left(\frac 1a-\frac 1b\right)>0\\&\iff b-a>0 \\&\iff a<b.
\end{align}

Comment: The OP said multiplication of an inequality is not allowed. Anyway (+1) : )

Comment: This is a good elementary proof ; if the OP is at the end of his high school with a knowledge of functions and derivatives, I have given a proof that I consider as more general.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

$$f_1:x \to \sqrt{x} \ \ \text{and} \ \ f_2:x \to \dfrac{1}{x}$$

(from $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ to itself).

The two properties to be established can be written in the following way:

$a<b \iff f_1(a)<f_1(b) \ \ $ (resp. $a<b \iff f_2(a)>f_2(b)),$

where we recognize the increasing (resp. decreasing) property for a bijective function $f$.

Thus we have to check that $f_1$ (resp. $f_2$) are bijective and increasing (resp. bijective and decreasing):

- bijectivity is checked by exhibiting an inverse of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (easy),
- increasing (resp. decreasing) property by proving that derivatives $f'_1$ (resp. $f'_2$) are always $>0$ (resp. $<0$) on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ (easy as well).